# Convert all collection in a single db into new dbs

Tags: mongodb

can you please help me,
I am trying to copy all collections in a particular database into create new database and move that collection into it.But the following code does not work. and my colleciton name in the db contains two part  ' mg2.data' ,'mg32.data' i want to create new database mg2 and copy collection name as data. 
collection name mg2.data suppose to be in mg2 database and collection name data.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function( a ){
if(a!='system.indexes' ) {
var sp = a.split('.');
var dbName = sp[0];
var col = sp[1];
//print(dbName)

db[a].copyTo(db.getSiblingDB(dbName).getcCollection(col));

}
});
```

Here is my situation details.

I am having Db name Master and it contains about 60-70 collections its names like(mg1.data,mg2.data,mg3.data)
and i want it to be like 
db name mg1 and collection name data
db name mg2 and collection name data and so on..
i am facing the problem that when in the first design write operation locks entire database(Master). i cannot go for sharding and all now.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't copy the database directly?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Is there any error reported?

Comment: Please re-phrase your question, it is incomprehensible.

Comment: Why not just mongoexport the collection from the old database and mongoimport it into the new database. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Please give a clearer explanation of your objective and the problem you're having trying to reach it...right I don't know what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this approach working for me.I dont know is this best aproach

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function( a ){
if(a!='system.indexes' ) {
var sp = a.split('.');
var dbName = sp[0];
var col = sp[1];
print(dbName+'\n');

//db[a].copyTo(db.getSiblingDB(dbName).getcCollection(col));
db[a].find().forEach(function(d){ db.getSiblingDB(dbName)[col].insert(d); });

}
});
```